# WSO2 ESB avoid xml declaration in endpoint

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have to develop a Passthroug ProxyService in WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 to call a web service developed in B1WS.

When I try to call the B1WS service directly from SoapUI, it only works if I don't specify the encoding in the xml declaration

Request with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Has the response:

```
<Error>System Id = 186454128, Line Number = 2, Column Number = 1, Description = Invalid document structure</Error>
```

But Request with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

Has a valid response

When I create the ProxyService in WSO2 ESB, it automatically adds the encoding to the XML declaration, so the request is not accepted by the B1WS service. How can I avoid this?

Comment: what is the content-type your B1WS service is expecting?  Is it plain/text?

Comment: When using SoapUI, it uses `Content-Type: text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1`, but it works also with charset utf-8 or utf-16, and Content-Type application/soap+xml